# How is sequence syntactic sugar ([1..6]) translated into actual list syntax ( 1:2:3...6 )?

Tags: list, haskell, syntax, enumeration, syntactic-sugar

How does Haskell translate `[` and `]` into the list definitions? Are they value constructors or something? Are they newtypes? Is there a way to define an *outfix* syntax, as opposed to an infix one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This syntax is defined in the [Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/), and in particular in [section 3.10](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-400003.10). `[1..6]` is defined to mean `enumFromTo 1 6`. You can't define syntax like that yourself.

Comment: To emphasize---`[1, 2, 3]` and `[1..3]` have the same *value*, but arrive there in very different ways. `[1, 2, 3]` desugars (directly!) to `1:2:3:[]` while `[1..3]` desugars to `enumFromTo 1 3` which then *evaluates* to `1:2:3:[]`.

Comment: @tel: and for completeness, `[1,2,3]` and `[1..3]` don't necessarily have the same value. It depends what it's type is. It could be a list of a type that implements `Enum` in a weird way.

Comment: One could also be a type error as the principle type of `[1,2,3]` is `Num a => [a]` while the principle type of `[1..3]` is `(Num a, Enum a) => [a]`.